# Correct location of openssl.cnf file

Tags: openssl

I have an Ubuntu system and I have installed OpenSSL. Now I want to make changes to the config file. I searched my folders and found the following locations for the config files. Which is the main/correct one that I should use to make changes? I need to add an engine here. Any help would be appreciated. Here are the locations:

```
/usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf

This is a local installation. You downloaded and built OpenSSL taking the default `prefix`, of you configured with `./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl` or `./config --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl`.

You will use this **if** you use the OpenSSL in `/usr/local/ssl/bin`. That is, `/usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf` will be used when you issue:

```
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -tls1 -servername localhost
```

---

> /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

This is where Ubuntu places `openssl.cnf` for the OpenSSL they provide.

You will use this **if** you use the OpenSSL in `/usr/bin`. That is, `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` will be used when you issue:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -tls1 -servername localhost
```

---

> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

I don't know when this is used. The stuff in `/etc/ssl` is usually certificates and private keys, and it sometimes contains a copy of `openssl.cnf`. But I've never seen it used for anything.

---

> Which is the main/correct one that I should use to make changes?

From the sounds of it, you should probably add the engine to `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf`. That ensures most "off the shelf" gear will use the new engine.

After you do that, add it to `/usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf` also because copy/paste is easy.

---

Here's how to see which `openssl.cnf` directory is associated with a OpenSSL installation. The library and programs look for `openssl.cnf` in `OPENSSLDIR`. `OPENSSLDIR` is a configure option, and its set with `--openssldir`.

I'm on a MacBook with 3 different OpenSSL's (Apple's, MacPort's and the one I build):

```
# Apple    
$ /usr/bin/openssl version -a | grep OPENSSLDIR
OPENSSLDIR: "/System/Library/OpenSSL"

# MacPorts
$ /opt/local/bin/openssl version -a | grep OPENSSLDIR
OPENSSLDIR: "/opt/local/etc/openssl"

# My build of OpenSSL
$ openssl version -a | grep OPENSSLDIR
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl/darwin"
```

---

> I have an Ubuntu system and I have installed openssl.

<strike>Just bike shedding, but be careful of Ubuntu's version of OpenSSL. It disables TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2, so you will only have clients capable of older cipher suites; and you will not be able to use newer ciphers like AES/CTR (to replace RC4) and elliptic curve gear (like `ECDHE_ECDSA_*` and `ECDHE_RSA_*`). See [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: OpenSSL downlevel version is 1.0.0, and does not support TLS 1.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576) in Launchpad.</strike>

**EDIT**: Ubuntu enabled TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 recently. See [Comment 17](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576/comments/17) on the bug report.

Comment: I believe `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` is just a symbolic link to the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`, as that is what is in in my install of openssl. 
`file /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf`  gives `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf: symbolic link to '/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf'`

Answer (score 64):

RHEL: /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf

Comment: Same with centos 7.x

Comment: Same with Fedora 31.

Comment: Same with CentOS 8.x

Comment: So roughly 70 up-voters did not read even the first 4 words:)

Answer (score 26):

You can run the following command to get the location of `openssl.cnf` file:

```
% openssl version -d
```

On my computer, the result is:

```
% openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"
```

The path of `openssl.cnf` file:

```
% echo "$(openssl version -d | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"/\1/g')/openssl.cnf"
/private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Comment: Using openssl version -d works on Windows 11 as well

Answer (score 15):

> /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf

is soft link of

> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

You can see that using long list **(ls -l)** on the /usr/local/ssl/ directory where you will find

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Mar  1 05:15 openssl.cnf ->
>   /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

Comment: Which environment has this symlink?  I had a quick look on a few different unixy systems (Ubuntu, CentOS, MacOS, Git for Windows) and I couldn't find any with a /usr/local/ssl/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

On my CentOS 6 I have two openssl.cnf :

```
/openvpn/easy-rsa/
/pki/tls/
```

Comment: Since this is a very old question, could you add a bit more info to your answer to justify it being relevant?