# Sitecore 9.3 Setup | xConnect | Failure with SSL SQL Connection

Tags: sql-server, ssl, installation, database-connection, sitecore

Sitecore setup fails with this issue as in the image.

From the Logs we have

```
[------------ XConnectXP0_CreateShards : Command -----------------------------][ShardingTool - Create]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93-dev02-xconnect.dev.local\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe
```

```
[ XConnectXP0_CreateShardApplication... : InvokeSqlcmd ------------------------]A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)[TIME] 00:04:17A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
```

This seems to be an SQL SSL setup issue, havent come across this in my earlier installations. Any pointers to fix this would be greatly appreciated

Gated while installing Sitecore ver 9.3 via SIF or PS Scripts

Comment: Try specifying `TrustServerCertificate=Yes` in the connection string or reach out to your DBA to see if a certificate has been provisioned.

Comment: I'd guess you are affected by the "Secure by default" breaking change that was added to drivers, such as [OLEDB 19](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#1900).

Comment: I followed this blog to install an SSL certificate on my local SQL Server https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=create-install-ssl-tls-certificate-sql-server. Further issues were resolved by using the correct CN at the time of SQL connection.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have this issue at the step 53 of SIF installer or face this issue using powershell scripts

Use this blog https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=create-install-ssl-tls-certificate-sql-server to install the Self signed certificate on SQL server.

At the time of creating the connection string, ensure that you use the same "server name" as the CN used at the time of creating the SSL certificate.

[Error Loading extension section for ssl_server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612278/error-loading-extension-section-for-ssl-server) gives steps to find the correct openssl configuration file to make changes to add settings as called out in the blog in the answer

get the ssl installer from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and use the FULL installer link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612278/error-loading-extension-section-for-ssl-server gives steps to find the correct openssl configuration file to make changes to add settings as called out in the blog in the answer

get the ssl installer from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and use the FULL installer link