# How to determine the default location for openssl.cnf?

Tags: bash, openssl

## Background

I'm writing a bash script that will use openssl to generate a certificate signing request with *X509v3 extension compliant* subject alternative names.

Since there's no command line option for this, [a solution](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/10/openssl-csr-with-alternative-names-one.html?m=1#c5955230974051418639) has been to use the `-config` option in conjunction with the `-reqexts` option by appending the SAN values inline to the default configuration file.

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=Acme, Inc./CN=example.com" -reqexts SAN -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com")) -out domain.csr
```

## Question

My problem is portability. While [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477210/correct-location-of-openssl-cnf-file) assures me that this works in my Ubuntu environment because the default configuration file is `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`, unfortunately this won't work everywhere, with Windows being the obvious example.

*How do I **programmatically** determine the full path to the openssl **default** configuration file?*

## What I've Tried

There's a glaring hint in the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/req.html)

> -config filename
>   this allows an alternative configuration file to be specified, this overrides **the compile time filename** or any specified in the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable.

I've read the [config documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/config.html) and searched the [source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl), but I can't discover the mechanism by which it chooses from where to load the "compile time" default config file. If I could find that, then I would prefer to load it as a variable into the script instead of the hard-coded path.

Moreover, my `$OPENSSL_CONF` variable is empty.

### A Bad Alternative

Currently my script checks these conditions, and uses the first one that evaluates to true:

1. `$OPENSSL_CONF` variable is populated, and file exists
2. `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` exists

If neither of those are true, then it includes a copy of a standard configuration. This is undesirable because it would in effect override custom settings established by the client. I want to use the environment's conditions completely, and simply add the SAN section as an addendum.

I could further extend this chain with the paths of the usual suspects or even a system search. But in the event that multiple exist, then I have no assurance of which is in fact used by openssl as a default.

Comment: Why not just create an `openssl.cnf` file for your script, and use it explicitly with `-config`?  That seems much easier than trying to determine the system-specific default.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, I need to update my question. That's my current fallback, but I don't like the idea of presuming to override any other configurations the client may have.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How do I programmatically determine the full path to the openssl default configuration file?

Programmatically, its as easy as using the `OPENSSLDIR` macro from `opensslconf.h`:

```
$ cat /usr/local/ssl/darwin/include/openssl/opensslconf.h | grep OPENSSLDIR
#if defined(HEADER_CRYPTLIB_H) && !defined(OPENSSLDIR)
#define OPENSSLDIR "/usr/local/ssl/darwin"
```

---

> How to determine the default location for openssl.cnf?

Here's more information to help fill in the gaps from the other Stack Overflow question. It depends on the OpenSSL installation you are using.

Here's the short answer... The library and programs look for `openssl.cnf` in `OPENSSLDIR`. `OPENSSLDIR` is a configure option, and its set with `--openssldir`.

I'm on a MacBook with 3 different OpenSSL's (Apple's, MacPort's and the one I build):

```
# Apple    
$ /usr/bin/openssl version -a | grep OPENSSLDIR
OPENSSLDIR: "/System/Library/OpenSSL"

# MacPorts
$ /opt/local/bin/openssl version -a | grep OPENSSLDIR
OPENSSLDIR: "/opt/local/etc/openssl"

# My build of OpenSSL
$ openssl version -a | grep OPENSSLDIR
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl/darwin"
```

Here's the longer answer... It is kind of buried in OpenSSL source code for `apps.c`, `load_config` and what happens when `cnf` is `NULL` (i.e., no `-config` option or `OPENSSL_CONF` envar). When `cnf` is `NULL` and no overrides, then `OPENSSLDIR` is used.

```c
int load_config(BIO *err, CONF *cnf)
{
    static int load_config_called = 0;
    if (load_config_called)
        return 1;
    load_config_called = 1;
    if (!cnf)
        cnf = config;
    if (!cnf)
        return 1;

    OPENSSL_load_builtin_modules();

    if (CONF_modules_load(cnf, NULL, 0) <= 0) {
        BIO_printf(err, "Error configuring OpenSSL\n");
        ERR_print_errors(err);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

---

> ... this works in my Ubuntu environment because the default configuration file is `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`, unfortunately this won't work everywhere, with Windows being the obvious example.

This may still be a problem for you on Windows. You should be OK if you build OpenSSL from sources yourself; modulo their long filename handling in Windows (also see [Issue #4490: "nmake install" fails "Destination must be a directory at .\util\copy.pl line 39" on](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=4490&user=guest&password=guest)).

Folks like [Shinning Light and Win32 OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) provide installers, and OpenSSL *may not* be installed in the directory the packager envisioned. I've even seen Unix directories like `/usr/local` appear on Windows machines.

For Windows, your safest bet is probably set the `OPENSSL_CONF` environmental variable to override broken paths and path handling bugs.

---

Also, I'm not aware of a `CONF_*` or `NCONF_*` API call that gives you the effective directory at runtime. Here, the effective directory would be the configuration directory plus things like `OPENSSL_CONF` overrides. Now open on the OpenSSL User list: [Get effective OPENSSLDIR path at runtime?](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2016-May/003664.html)

Comment: I had overlooked the [version documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/version.html) which I see now provides a flag for the `OPENSSLDIR` with `openssl version -d`. This works for me and is a verbosely well written and sincerely appreciated answer. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @JeffPuckettII - Lol.... Its easy once you know what to look for and where to look :)

Answer (score 27):

As mentioned in one of the comments, the easy answer should be to find the path using the following command:

```
openssl version -d
```

If this doesn't work, you could presume that OpenSSL is not correctly configured, or at least doesn't have the configuration you need. Here is an example in Node.js on how you could get the location of openssl.cnf:

```
const util = require('util');
const path = require('path');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

(async () => {
    const opensslCnfPath = path.normalize(`${(await exec('openssl version -d')).stdout.match(/"(.*)"/).pop()}/openssl.cnf`);
    console.log(opensslCnfPath);
})();
```